# EF Core Conventions for datetime2

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've worked on an EF 6 project where in framework code we had a Convention defined to ensure that all entity POCOs that had a C# DateTime would map to datetime2 in Sql Server. Now that there's no Conventions how could I achieve this in EF Core?

Comment: How about something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629412/set-property-conventions-in-ef-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @DavidG. Based on the link you sent I think this will work (I'm on a corporate network right now with a group policy that's not allowing NuGet Package Manager Console to invoke the init.ps1 for entityframeworkcore.tools so I'll have to wait to try this at home)

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var dateTimeProps = entity.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime));
    foreach (var prop in dateTimeProps)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).Property(prop.Name).HasColumnType("datetime2");
    }

}
```

Comment: As per as I am concerned `Entity Framework Core` by default generate `datetime2` column for C# DateTime.

Comment: I think it depends on the version of Sql Server, but using this allows the precision of the datatype to be specified as well. I'm upgrading an existing framework that used Conventions in EF6 to ensure datetime2 was being used so I'm putting this in to be sure... plus some other Conventions